# Syntax errors in parametrizing stacks

Tags: java, syntax-error, generic-collections, stack

I'm a computer science student that just started my sophomore programming class and I'm having some real issues with a project that deals with Stacks and collections.

Basically, this is a project that relies on the ArrayStack Class(ArrayStack, to be specific) to convert mathematical expressions between postfix and infix forms.

Basically, ArrayStack is used to take in an expression like 45 * (26 - 5) / 54, turn it into a collection, then rewrite in a postfix form like 45 26 5 - * 54 /

The problem is, first of all, whenever I try to substitute  with Character in the main method(since the stack needs to store both operators and operands, maybe there's a better data type I'm missing here), I get some strange syntax error, usually involving the program thinking that ArrayStack.System is somehow a statement(System.out.println is right below an ArrayStack statement, which suggests there's some kind of syntax problem)

Here's the code I have so far:

```
public class ArrayStack<T> implements StackADT<T>
{   
    private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 100;
    private int top;
    private T[] stack;

    public ArrayStack() {
        top = -1;
        stack = (T[]) (new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY]);
    }
    public void push(T element) {
        stack[top+1] = element;
        top++;
    }
    public T pop()  {
        T element = stack[top];
        stack[top] = null;
        top--;
        return element;
    }
    public T peek() {
        return stack[top];
    }
    public boolean isEmpty()    {
        if(stack[0]==null)
            return true;
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public int size()   {
        int length = 0;
        for(int count=0;count<stack.length;count++) {
            if(stack[count]!=null)  {
                length++;
            }
            else if(stack[count]==null) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return length;
    }
    public String toString()    {
        String array = "";
        for(int count=0;count<stack.length;count++) {
            array = array+stack[count]+" ";
        }
        return array;
    }


}
```

And for the main method:

```
public class StackTester {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        boolean quit = false;
        int input;
        String expression;
        do  {
            System.out.println("1. Convert infix to postfix");
            System.out.println("2. Convert postfix to infix");
            System.out.println("3. Exit.");

            java.util.Scanner keyboard = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
            input = keyboard.nextInt();

            switch(input)   {
            case 1:
                //ArrayStack stack = new ArrayStack();
                //System.out.println("Enter an infix expression: ");
                expression = keyboard.next();
                for(int count=0;count<expression.length();count++)  {
                    Character a = expression.charAt(count);
                    stack.push(a);
                }
                for(int count=stack.size()-1;count>=0;count--)  {
                    if(stack.peek()=='+')   {

                    }
                }

            }
            break;
        }

        while(!quit);
    }

}
```

The error usually occurs at the lines marked with //, every time I try to insert something like  or otherwise, the program gives some weird syntax error like its trying to read it together with the line below it. Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: You should include the error message you received. But it looks like you need to specify the type to be stored in the stack...

Comment: The main error I'm getting now is Error on tokens, expression expected instead. As for specifying the type to be stored, every time I try that I just get that same syntax error, like I'm writing it wrong. I'm writing it out ArrayStack<Character> stack = new ArrayStack<Character;>, but apparently that's no good...

Comment: Give the exact error message including the line number. Show us with a comment which line it is. You don't need a semi-colon inside the `<>`.